# one or more projects require a platform SDK(UAP, 10.0.16299.91)

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, win-universal-app

I am trying to open the UWP project but however because of versioning issue I am not able to load the project. It gives me following error.

[image]

However, this version is already installed and even I have tried to install it again. But even after that is again giving me the same error.

I have updated the project version in .csproj file also as below. The version which is mentioned in the screenshot is already installed.

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.16299.91</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299.15</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

After doing all this it still gives the error as Visual Studio Update Required.

Any help on this appreciated!

Comment: try uninstall and reinstall and install this version of sdk from your vs installer instead of windows10 sdk installer

Comment: @ShubhamSahu you are saying i need to repair visual studio ?

Comment: try to set targets as:

`<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.16299</TargetPlatformVersion>`
`<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299</TargetPlatformMinVersion>`

Comment: @Rohit no i am talking about uninstall and reinstall sdk through vs_installer instead of sdk setup or if dont want this you can also try jet chopper suggestion right click on solution in vs and edit csproj file and edit target and min version but this may cause dependency error but you can try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to target your project to 10.0.16299.91 from your csproj, you can specific the target version to 10.0.16299.0 as Jet suggested. The build version is different from target version.

Thinking about this, if your customer is on 10.0.16299.0, then he cannot use your app? This is not reasonable. By the way, when you load your project, it will asks you to retarget your project, you can find the supported target version listed there.